# Getting maximum value from a column in a MySQL table, increasing value by 1 and passing to variable

Tags: mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, max

I am using the query below to extract the maximum value of a column called id in a MySQL table, so that I can increase it's value by 1 and pass it to a variable called $fav_id.  For some reason $fav_id is returning '0', instead of the value I want, i.e. if the maximum current value in the id column is 465, then $fav_id should be set to 466.  Perhaps someone could let me know where I am going wrong.

```
$sth2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM tracks");

$sth2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

while($row = $sth2->fetch()) {
    $fav_id = $row->id+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping $row->id+1 in parenthesis, like ($row->id)+1, and keep an eye out for scoping. You might want to set $fav_id to 0 outside of the while loop to establish it has a larger scope then just the while loop.

Comment: Have you tried setting $fav_id to like -1 and then see if it remains -1? If so, that will say right there that the while loop isn't being entered at all. I wonder though... is $sth2->fetch actually returning anything at all? If not, then that could be giving you a false negative.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge of PDOs, it should be $row[id] not $row->id. Also, you never executed the prepared statement, but since you don't have any placeholders in the query you should use '->query' instead of '->prepare'